# How to select these unclassified elements in QueryPath

Tags: php, regex, querypath

Here is the HTML in question:

```
<div class="logo-wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li>
          Contact: <strong>I need this</strong>
      </li>
      <li>
        Location: <strong>and this</strong>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My first instinct was to use eq(0) and eq(1) on the li elements, but there are occasions when either the contact or location may not be present and the order of li will change. I have also tried to use filterPreg() to select the 'Contact:' and 'Location:' text but this does not seem to work as I expected.

Short of using `find('.logo-wrapper')->text()` and then using a standard regexp to get what I need, is there any way of keeping this inside QueryPath?

Comment: You want find it with php or javascript? (cuz there's no javascript-tag to your question) - further, any chance to give those li classes?

Comment: It's PHP that I'm using, and unfortunately no the li's cannot be given classes (that'd be too easy :))

Comment: I doubt that you can do it with QueryPath functions only. Cuz you can't differentiate if it's a contact or a location. Looks like you've to use regexp at least one time for your crawler ;)

Comment: Damn shame. Is the filterPreg() search function in QP no good for this? I did try something along the lines of `find('.logo-wrapper')->filterPreg('/Contact:/')->find('strong')->text()` but if I remember rightly it returned both sets of li text

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301813/using-querypath-filterpreg-to-locate-text-not-working <- i c

Comment: http://api.querypath.org/docs/class_query_path.html#aed6de5251b412ee5d098c2a332530e7f says that if you filter for 'Contact:' it should return LI - looks like it ignores your find('strong'). Maybe try deepest() to get the 'strong'-Tag.